# Ember.js: Dynamic width based on model attribute value

Tags: ember.js

First-time Ember user here.  In the app, my model objects are each represented by a rectangular-shaped `<div>` element. The width of each div is determined by its model's `size` property.  The catch is that the possible values for `Model.size` are 1-10, not simply pixel values. The div's width is then calculated based on the `size`.  For example, a `size` of **1** might equal a width of **100px**, and a `size` of **2** would equal **200px**, and so on.  Thus, these CSS width values need to be calculated and bound to the template. Being new to Ember, I don't yet know where this logic should live. Helper? Controller? Because it's really just presentation logic, it doesn't seem right to have it in the model.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="things">
  {{#each model}}
    <div>
      {{description}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Also, will binding it to the template allow the calculated width to be updated automatically in the template whenever the `Model.size` value is changed (say, from 1 to 3, thus the div would grow wider)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is a good idea to keep presentation and logic separate, sometimes they need to be mixed. I've certainly had use cases. I used [this helper](https://github.com/yderidde/bindstyle-ember-helper) when I had a similar issue. Assuming you had this property in your model:

```
divWidth: function() {
    return this.get('size') * 100;
}.property('size')
```

You could use this template (which is bound to the property value):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="things">
    {{#each model}}
        <div {{bindStyle width="divWidth" width-unit="px"}}>
            {{description}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the **right** way to do this, but you should be able to do it this way. You can add a function to your controller (or, I believe your model as well) that listens to the `size` property for changes, and then calls a jQuery function.

i.e.

```
changeSize: function() {
    return $('#things').css( 'width', this.get('size') * 100);
}.property('size')
```

Also, you could create a computed property in your model the calculates the size for you:

```
divSize: function() {
    return this.get('size') * 100;
}.property('size')
```

And you'd reference the `divSize` in `changeSize` function, which would be useful if your conversion was more complicated than just multiplying by 100. The helper in the other answer looks useful and more Ember-esque, but here's another way it could be done.